# git hard reset - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: git, github, hash

I have Problem: I wanted to commit something but instead commited the whole location where the folder which was meant to be commited were in. So now I have like way too many Files and folders in my Github and I really just want to get back to where I was before. That's why I tried hard reset, which I found online. 
So first I did "git log" and copied the hash of the HEAD I wanted to restore. Then I told my console "git reset --hard HASH" Of course I filled in my Hash where now stands HASH. After doing this whats o ever the files in git dont change online. I thought I might have to pull first and push then. I also tried to just commit and push. Still, no matter what I do, the files online won't change.
Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you've described your flow correctly, you did these things in this order:

- Worked from a remote branch
- Committed work that you didn't intend to commit
- Pushed that work to your remote
- Wish to revert to before you pushed

In that case, you would perform this.

**WARNING:  This is a good way to lose work.  If you're working with others, be sure you have their blessing.  If you're *sure* you want to do this, carry on.**

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

This takes you back to the parent of where your HEAD reference is pointing.

You then would push the result of that to your remote branch.

```
git push
```

Comment: I tried this, but my push fails. The terminal says "Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull ...') before pushing again."

I also did that sometime, but then I just get the work I didn't want to commit :/

Comment: No, but they don't have a clue either

Comment: That ***drastically*** changes things.  Stop and go talk to them.  Like, right now.  If you do a force-push, you're going to mess them up and they'll be *yelling* at you behind it.

Comment: Oh they're not working on this at the moment. The code that now shall be produced is solemny mine. also, they know of the problem

Comment: See, another question: is there a way to delete folders in github? because i could just delete the trash i commited, then everything would be fine too :/ But by now I only see a way to remove files, but not folders

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to remove the remote branch and it's history.

I found instructions here: http://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/

`$ git rm --cached giant_file
   #Stage our giant file for removal, but leave it on disk
 $ git commit --amend -CHEAD
   #Amend the previous commit with your change
   #Simply making a new commit won't work, as you need
   #to remove the file from the unpushed history as well
 $ git push
   # Push our rewritten, smaller commit`

Comment: sadly it's not one big file :( Its many many folders and files

Comment: @HannahAround
I am not sure, but I think that globing works with this as well, so you could use:
`git rm --cached *`

Comment: if I do that, the terminal will answer `usage: git rm [options] [--] <file>...

    -n, --dry-run         dry run
    -q, --quiet           do not list removed files
    --cached              only remove from the index
    -f, --force           override the up-to-date check
    -r                    allow recursive removal
    --ignore-unmatch      exit with a zero status even if nothing matched
` (and I really don't know how to work with that)

Comment: In that case I think you would use `git rm --cached -r -f *`

Comment: you are my hero ! *_* What you said didn't work, but, when I said reset hard and then git push --force, it finally worked *____* All I had to do was force it :D Thank you thank you thank you

Comment: I'm glad we were able to muddle through it. I also found http://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/ which suggests using the BFG Repo Cleaner. That may have been an easier option, I will keep in it mind for the next time this happens to me.